# How to polyfill a Multi-polygon in H3?

Tags: geojson, h3

I have a set of multipolygons in GeoJSON format, for example:

```
{ 
  "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [[[102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0], [102.0, 3.0], [102.0, 2.0]]],
    [[[100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0]],
     [[100.2, 0.2], [100.8, 0.2], [100.8, 0.8], [100.2, 0.8], [100.2, 0.2]]]
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to use the `polyfill_geojson` method in the H3 library to get the hexagons that fall within it. But it seems like this method only supports Polygons and not multipolygons:

```
>>> h3.polyfill_geojson(geojson, 8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "python3.7/site-packages/h3/api/_api_template.py", line 486, in polyfill_geojson
    mv = _cy.polyfill_geojson(geojson, res)
  File "geo.pyx", line 186, in h3._cy.geo.polyfill_geojson
ValueError: Only Polygon GeoJSON supported
```

How can I get the H3 hexagons from a Multipolygon GeoJSON?

Answer (score 5):

Easy....this gives you a list of sets (which you can easily join).

```
 [h3.polyfill(shapely.geometry.mapping(x)) for x in list(shapely.geometry.loads(geojson))]
```

Comment: It has solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no support yet for multipolygons on an h3.polyfill like function.

I suggest you to programmatically separate the polygons from the multipolygon, and to evaluate the polyfill function over each one of these single polygons.

Or, if you are working on a small number of polygons, use the https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/ tool to create a polygon that matches the multipolygon.

Sorry if this does not help too much.

Answer (score 0):

The function that might help here is `mosaicfill` from Mosaic library which is an extension to the Apache Spark framework that allows easy and fast processing of very large geospatial datasets https://databrickslabs.github.io/mosaic/

https://databrickslabs.github.io/mosaic/api/spatial-functions.html?highlight=mosaic_fill#mosaicfill

Unlike the native H3 implementation, Mosaic wrapper function does handle multi geometries

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html) to convert the multipolygons to polygons.

After that, you can probably work out the rest (and do a more elegant job!), but I did this:

> ```
> hexagons = []
> for index, row in geofence.iterrows():
>   hexagons.extend(h3.polyfill(row['geometry'].__geo_interface__, h3resolution, geo_json_conformant=True))
> ```

Comment: sorry, I'm new to GIS stuff.  what is `geofence` here?

Comment: Sorry, geofence is a GeoDataFrame containing polygons (after exploding from multipolygons).

Answer (score 0):

for anyone using H3-js
inspiration: https://github.com/vasturiano/three-globe/blob/7717c8e54c98dcb3e92df5a95923f51387a496a1/src/layers/hexedPolygons.js#L110

```js
const hexagons = []

features.forEach(feature=> {
    switch (feature.geometry.type) {
        case 'Polygon':
            h3.polygonToCells(features.geometry.coordinates, resolution, true).forEach(h3Idx => hexagons.push(h3.cellToBoundary(h3Idx, true).reverse()));
            break;
        case 'MultiPolygon':
            feature.geometry.coordinates.forEach(coords =>
                h3.polygonToCells(coords, resolution, true).forEach(h3Idx => hexagons.push(h3.cellToBoundary(h3Idx, true).reverse()))
            );
            break;
        default:
            console.warn(`Unsupported geometry type: ${features.geometry.type}. Skipping this feature`);
            break;
    }
})

const geojson = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: hexagons.map(hexagon => ({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Polygon',
            coordinates: [hexagon]
        },
        properties: {}
    }))
};
```

Comment: you may also want to convert it to topojson as we have a tons of shared boundary here.